# segmentation fault on strcpy();

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>


typedef struct client
{
    int threadid;
    int argc;
    char *argv[3];
} client;

void exit(int status);
void error(char *msg);

void *threadClient(void *socket_desc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    client info[10];
    pthread_t thread[10];

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);

    // Error happens here

    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        info[i].threadid = i;
        strcpy(info[i].argv[0], argv[0]);
        strcpy(info[i].argv[1], argv[1]);
        strcpy(info[i].argv[2], argv[2]);
        info[i].argc = argc;
        printf("here");
        if (pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, threadClient, (void*)&info[i]) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        sleep(3);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;

}
```

During the loop, when I am trying to copy the info from `argv` to my struct I get a segmentation fault. Why does it happen?

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
> 296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: 1) `i<=10` --> `i<10` 2) `strcpy(info[i].argv[0], argv[0]);` `info[i].argv[0]` doesn't initialized.

Comment: i changed the for loop i problem thank you i didn't noticed i put that there. but how would i go about initializing it?

Comment: `info[i].argv[0] = malloc(strlen(argv[0])+1);` before `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problem here.

First, your `argv` array in your `info` structure is an array of pointers.  These start out uninitialized.  When you later call `strcpy`, giving one of these array elements as the first parameter, it expects that pointer to point to valid memory.  So you end up dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  This  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a segfault.

You need to assign something to these pointers.  You can either use `strdup` to make a copy of these strings:

```
info[i].argv[0] = strdup(argv[0]);
info[i].argv[1] = strdup(argv[1]);
info[i].argv[2] = strdup(argv[2]);
```

Or, if you don't plan on modifying these values, you can just copy the pointer values directly:

```
info[i].argv[0] = argv[0];
info[i].argv[1] = argv[1];
info[i].argv[2] = argv[2];
```

The second issue is an off-by-one error in your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
```

Because you use `<=`, your indexes into the array will range from 0 to 10.  However, your array only has 10 elements (with indexes 0 to 9), so you're writing past the end of the array.  This also invokes undefined behavior.

Change your conditional to `<` as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your struct is defined to contain three pointers (`char *argv[3]`). When you create an array of those structs in the stack (`client info[10]`) space is reserved for these pointers, among other things. The structs aren't initalized to anything, so the pointers don't point to any sensible memory location. Hence, accessing them as with `strcpy(info[i].argv[0], argv[0]);` is in error.

Either allocate the space you use explicitly:

```
info[i].argv[0] = malloc(strlen(argv[0])+1);
strcpy(info[i].argv[0], argv[0]);
```

Or use `strdup()` to copy the strings:

```
info[i].argv[0] = strdup(argv[0]);
```

Remember to `free()` the space you allocated afterwards.

---

Also, I don't think you should declare a function called `exit()` yourself, it's a standard function and should be in `stdlib.h`.